# Forcing raspi-config to run automatically on next boot

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3, raspbian, boot

Once the RasPi boots for first time, it shows the raspi-config utitliy. But on next boot it's gone.

I would like to run it during first boot, do some configuration stuff, and then re-enable it in order to automatically run one more time on the next (or second) boot. I found this link, but it seems that it's outdated and couldn't make it work: https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=103512

Is there a command that I can run on the terminal before shutting down the RasPi (during first boot) that re-enables raspi-config to automatically run on the next start? Or is there something I can edit in a configuration file?

Comment: You should be able to use `/etc/rc.local` https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/72719

Comment: Thanks. However, will it work in a way that after that second boot, raspi-config does not show up again? I mean, what I need is to boot once, do some configuration, and then next time raspi-config shows as always, but behaving as it would do on a first boot, which means that in the "third boot" it will not showup.

Comment: Is there any particular reason you need to run raspi-config on every boot? Most of the raspi-config settings can be done via command line if you know Linux well. As@MarkSetchell point out, if you really want it to run in every boot, simply add `sudo raspi-config` in `/etc/rc.local` before the `exit 0` line.

Comment: Yes, there is a reason, but it's not on "every boot". What I need is: 1st Boot: Run it automatically. 2nd Boot: run it automatically. Never run it again automatically.

Comment: Write a shell script with if condition, and set it executable, then add it to /etc/rc.local.

Comment: Can you tell me more about the shell script. What should I ask for in that "if", for example? What I'm trying to get in this answer is what should I look in order for to determine if the raspi-config will run or not, or what config file to edit in order to make it run one more boot automatically.